# Load multiple python files in to dagster via dagit locally

Tags: python, data-science, etl, dagster

I am trying to figure out how to or if there is a way to use `dagit` command on multiple python job files.

Example: `dagit -f hello_cereal_job.py`

With in the directory I have multiple `*_job.py` files and when I launch the dagster ui locally with `dagit` I'd like to have all my jobs visible in the UI.

With this command it only shows me the one job that I have in the file, but I'd like to have all jobs from all files in my directory show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use repositories or workspaces for loading many entities

https://docs.dagster.io/concepts/repositories-workspaces/workspaces